# jquery change text and replace it with a link

Tags: jquery, html, hover, center

I want to change some text bij replacing it with a url when you move over it with the mouse.
I know you can't change it by using animation (that's for css) that's why i use fadeout.
After spending hours on it i still can't figure out why it doesn't work.

I'd also like the whole div in the center of the page, i tried valign etc but that doesn't work neither. It isn't a priority but it'd be nice to replace the margin-top

```
<div align="center" style="margin-top: 20%;"> 
  <div id="change">
    <p id="big">Welcome!</p>
  </div>
  <img src="pic.JPG" alt="Logo" width="40%" height="90"/>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$("#change").hover(
function(){
    $(this).find('p').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $(this).text('<a href="Index.html">Continue</a>').fadeIn('slow'); 
    });
}, 
function(){
    $(this).find('p').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $(this).text('Welcome').fadeIn('slow'); 
    });    
});
</script>
```

THX in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Use `html` method:

```
$(this).html('<a href="Index.html">Continue</a>').fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: Seems not to be what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not so easy as I thought.

the mouseenter/over mouseleave/out is too easily triggered when moving the mouse fast so this:

```
<div align="center" style="margin-top: 20%;"> 
  <div id="change">
    <p id="big">Welcome!</p>
    <p id="link" style="display:none"><a href="Index.html">Continue</a></p>
  </div>
  <img src="pic.JPG" alt="Logo" width="40%" height="90"/>
</div>
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $("#change").hover(function(){
    $("#big").fadeOut('slow',function() {
      $("#link").fadeIn('slow');
    });
  },
  function(){
    $("#link").fadeOut('slow',function() {
      $("#big").fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
});
```

ALMOST works. but due to the enter/leave events, you may see both on the screen

If however we use [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) it works - you will need to download and include the [jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js) first

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/CRU42/)

```
$("#change").hoverIntent(function(){
    $("#big").fadeOut('slow',function() {
      $("#link").fadeIn('slow');
    });
  },
  function(){
    $("#link").fadeOut('slow',function() {
      $("#big").fadeIn('slow');
    });
  }    
);
```

or if you insist on changing html: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LDXpx/)

```
$("#change").hoverIntent(function(){
    $("#big").fadeOut('slow',function() {
      $("#big").html('<a href="Index.html">Continue</a>').fadeIn('slow');
    });
  },
  function(){
    $("#big").fadeOut('slow',function() {
      $("#big").html('Welcome').fadeIn('slow');
    });
  }    
);
```

Comment: this works but what i'm trying to do is replacing the text. when you move over it continue appears and when you move out of it welcome appears again

Comment: Which it does without the need to replace. Same problem with the hover though, I think we need the hoverintent plugin

Comment: This doesn't work neither. The previous method changed it but these 2 don't show any change at all :s Maybe i should add that all my code in packed in another div. But it's just a container... I don't understand this anymore

Comment: It is of course impossible to help you if you do not post the complete story. My code works in the fiddle using your html as you posted it. You need to include http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js after jQuery

Comment: can email it to you? i don't like posting my whole page